# Scraping google shopping with Nokogiri and SelectorGadget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, google-shopping

Rails 4

I'm attempting to implement a simple way to pull back pricing information from a google shopping search: https://www.google.com/search?q=arc%27teryx+beta+ar+pant&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=arc%27teryx+beta+ar+pant&tbs=vw:l&tbm=shop

Following the RailsCast on using Nokogiri and SelectorGadget, I was easily able to implement this on a walmart.com page.  When I changed this to pull results from google shopping, however, I get no results.  My @doc.css comes back blank.

**Controller:**

```
  def index
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=arc%27teryx+beta+ar+pant&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=arc%27teryx+beta+ar+pant&tbs=vw:l&tbm=shop"
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end
```

**View:**

```
# ".pslmain" is the listing container provided by SelectorGadget
<% @doc.css(".pslmain").each do |item| %>
  Title: <%=  item.at_css(".pstl").text %><br>
  Price: <%= item.at_css(".b").text[/\$[0-9\.]+/] %><br>
  Link:  <%= item.at_css(".pstl")[:href] %><br><br><br>
<% end %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have edited the view to show a different root URL, but that's not the issue

Comment: I can't see any results from the link provided. Not familiar with Nokogiri's full syntax but assuming the code has already been proven to work with Walmart, you should probably look at the variable inputs, i.e. Link, CSS (i.e. .pslmain) etc

Comment: Pasting into jsfiddle, it looks like it's pulling back results from a google web search instead of google products: https://jsfiddle.net/yvebotnn/ .  This is a bit odd since the url correctly ends with &tbm=shop